# ctags make empty index file for html

Tags: macos, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Ctags make empty index file for .html

I install from Macports new ctags 5.8 and try make index file for my project. But no "tags" file contain only headers

What i can generate "tags" for HTML file?

MacOS 10.6.2 ctags 5.8

Comment: `tags` are primarily used to jump to function definitions or variable declarations in a given language. Regarding pure HTML, I don't understand what functionality do you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter `ctags --list-kinds=HTML` you'll see the kinds of tags ctags can make for HTML files. For example:

`$ ctags --list-kinds=HTML

a  named anchors

f  JavaScript functions`

If you're wanting to search a bunch of HTML files you can always use `:vimgrep mytag **`